# What is the latest news with Adobe AIR? 

Tags: adobe, adobe-air

What are the latest news with Adobe AIR?
Is someone planing to develop a support for AIR. My business is using Adobe AIR for digital signage software on PC. I prefer Linux but without support or any other solution for AIR it means I need to buy Windows licenses. :(

Comment: You might succeed in getting the windows version running under wine but it depends on what you want to do with it. I wanted to use a desktop widget from the UK Met Office. I succeeded with the installation of AIR in wine and the install of the Met Office weather widget but the widget failed to download anything from the Met Office web site. It claimed it did not have Internet access. I installed the Adobe AIR settings manager but it has very few settings to adjust. The AIR scripts seemed to be pointing to the correct web address. I gave up in frustration.

Answer (score 5):

Adobe dropped Linux support in version 2.7 but you can still get and install version 2.6. If that's good enough for you, knowing it's not going to get an update, bug fixes or (importantly) security fixes, you can go ahead with that.

There is more information about this [on their kb page](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/521/cpsid_52132.html).

If the computer is not network-attatched and there's no foreseeable security risk from any flaw in Air, I reckon you could just go with that. I think you'd have to be running untrusted content to ever have any major issues with it.

On a side note, Adobe seems to want to transition everything over to HTML5. In the not-too-distant future the tools you're using now (or, more likely an upgraded license of them) might be able to output something you could just load up in a browser (in kiosk mode) on the display, cutting out the need for Air runtimes.